# How can I make a search in Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have this code here:

```
class AdminModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        column_searchable_list = ['username', 'email']
        column_filters = ['admin', 'confirm email']
        page_size = 50

        if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.is_anonymous:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
            if user.admin == True:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False


admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(User, db.session))
```

I am pretty sure that column_searchable_list should add a search bar, but it doesn't. Also, I can still filter by things other than admin and confirm email even though I defined column_filters. I have read the docs of flask-admin, and I don't see anything wrong. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You have your `column_searchable_list, column_filters, page_size` override assignments in the wrong place.

```
class AdminModelView(ModelView):

    column_searchable_list = ['username', 'email']
    column_filters = ['admin', 'confirm email']
    page_size = 50

    def is_accessible(self):
        # only accessible if admin field is True
        if current_user.is_authenticated and not current_user.is_anonymous:
            return current_user.admin

        return False


admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(User, db.session))
```